# How to make //example.com work on local files?

Tags: html, localhost

This is most likely a duplicate because I don't know the correct terms to search.

When looking at local files in the browser, the header will contain links like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works when they're loaded on a server and accessible over the internet. On localhost, in order to ensure the browser actually finds these I have to change it to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It won't load on localhost unless I specify. Problem is, when I'm working locally, I just want to be able to push the files up to the server when completed and not have to go back through looking for any of these links. Same when trying to make changes to what's already on the server. I don't want to pull them down, change all the links, then change them back when I'm finished.

How can I make these work properly on my local environment?

Comment: Try a work way round. Using PHP or something.
`If ($localhost) { $httpPrefix = "http://" } else { $httpPrefix = "//" }`